# How to delete element from react list and maintain indexes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to delete elements from a list on react but the way I've found to implement this requires a key to be assigned to reach element. I'm using the index from the list, but when I remove an item from the middle, it is always the last the one who disappears. How can I solve this?

This is how I'm removing the element (I've already logged the result and it is ok):

```
  handle_delete_elem(index){
    this.state.tasks.splice(index,1);
    this.setState({
      tasks: this.state.tasks
    });
  }
```

And this is how I'm looping through the list:

```
  get_task_list(){
    let task_list = [];

    if(this.state && this.state.tasks){
      for (var i = 0; i < this.state.tasks.length; i++) {
        task_list.push((
          <TaskItem
            key={i}
            index={i}
            handle_delete={this.handle_delete_elem}
            value={this.state.tasks[i].text}>
          </TaskItem>
        ));
      }
    }
    return task_list;
  }
```

Comment: Provide a minimal, working example by code snippet or codesandbox.

Comment: There is probably an error in the handle_delete callback from TaskItem component, sending an incorrect index

Comment: @AshKander No it is not, the index sent is correct, I've checked that already

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by used spread operators. 
I've refactored your code a bit:

```
class List extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            arr: [1,2,3,4,5]
        }
        this.get_task_list = this.get_task_list.bind(this);
        this.handle_delete_elem = this.handle_delete_elem.bind(this);
    }
    handle_delete_elem(index){
        let newArray = [ 
            ...this.state.arr.slice(0, index),
            ...this.state.arr.slice(index+1, this.state.arr.length)
        ];
        this.setState({
            arr: newArray
        });
   }
   get_task_list(){
    if(this.state && this.state.arr){
       return this.state.arr.map( (arrItem, index) => (
          <ListItem
            key={index}
            arrItem={arrItem}
            id={index}
            onClick={this.handle_delete_elem}
            />
        ));
    }
  }
  render(){
    return(
        <ul>{this.get_task_list()}</ul>
    )
  }
}

const ListItem = (props) => (
        <li onClick={() => props.onClick(props.id)}>{props.arrItem}</li>
);
```

Check this in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/83396/

Comment: Hi! this is great, but could you explain me why this works?